# TortoiseGit - no menu for remote under settings?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Trying to set a 2nd remote in TortoiseGit but I don't see a section under the Settings > Git

In the screenshot below there is a section for entering multiple remotes.  I only see the credentials section.  I'm using v2.6

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Remote" entry  (as well as the Issue Tracker Config) is only visible if TortoiseGit settings are opened on a Git working tree (i.e., rightclick on the specific versioned working tree and open settings from there).